# How to run a plugin only for "war" package type in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-plugin

Provided two Maven projects: J (jar), W (war); both depend on one parent P (pom). The parent has a plugin, which must only run for the project "W".

How does one go about doing this:

- without creating separate parent projects
- without using a profile (so build must still be executed with `mvn clean package`)

***J (jar)***

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>J</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

***W (war)***

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>W</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

***P (pom)***

```
<project>
  <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this using [Profile Activation](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html). Ideally, the activation condition would be something like "*packaging type is war*", but apparently, this condition cannot be implemented in Maven. However, in your case, there is a condition that *can* be implemented and that is probably equivalent in practice: "*there is a `src/main/webapp` directory*".

This is how your `pom.xml` might look like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>src/main/webapp</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            [plugin configuration]
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to place the plugin in the parent pom within `<pluginManagement>` section. Thereafter specify the plugin in the project(s) that you want it to run.

In your case, you would specify the plugin for project J and not W.

P

```
  <build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>...</groupId>
          <artifactId>...</artifactId>
          ...  other plugin details ...
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
   </build>
```

J

```
  <build>
    ...
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>...</groupId>
          <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <plugin>
      </plugins>
    ...
   </build>
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work, since the maven-jar-plugin will be executed implicitly on the "J" project (as it is a jar-based project).

Comment: @YuriyNemtsov. You asked how to run `a plugin`. Please ask precise question to get precise answers. My answer does apply in general.

Comment: Thank's for answering. In the question I've specifically asked that the plugin 'must only run for the project "W"'.

Comment: @YuriyNemstov. If you do not want to run `maven jar plugin` for a `jar` project, you may want to look at changing the project type to `pom`.

Comment: I do want to run the maven-jar-plugin for the "J" jar project, as well as for the "W" project. The only difference is that for the "W" project, I want to create an additional attached ("classifier") jar. Now, I can already do this by adding the maven-jar-plugin configuration directly to the "W" project; but since I have 20 "W" projects, that is a lot of duplicate config. As mentioned in the description, I also don't want to create separate parents for the war and jar projects.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Maven doesn't appear to have a good way to do what you're trying to do.  I've spent a fair amount of time trying to solve a similar problem and haven't found anything satisfactory.

You've already discovered two of the possible solutions: introduction of an additional parent pom for the wars (perhaps the additional pom extends the original parent so you don't have to duplicate all of its config), or duplicating the jar plugin config in all of the war poms.  As you've said, neither of these is ideal.

Another possibility is to use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) instead of the jar plugin to build the classified jar for the war projects.  The assembly plugin is not included in the default lifecycles for either jar or war packaging, so you could configure it in the parent's `<pluginManagement>` section and then only reference it in the war projects as Raghuram described.  If you need a custom assembly descriptor you will probably want to follow the [sharing the assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html) example.